# How do I check and display if multiple checkboxes are checked within a group box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, checkbox, nested-checkboxes

```
    For Each ctl As Windows.Forms.Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox Then
            Dim ck As System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox = ctl
            If ck.Checked Then
                intcheckboxesChecked += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

When I display the count its results to a 0 value

Comment: `For Each ctl As CheckBox In [GroupBox].Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox) If ctl.Checked Then ...` 
 -- You need to loop the Controls collection of the actual Parent -- This is VB.Net, VB6 is unrelated. I removed the tag.

Comment: As general advice, you should turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and in the VS options, so it will be `On` by default in future projects. You obviously have it set `Off` as your third line wouldn't compile otherwise. Setting it `On` will force you to think about data types and write more robust code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `CheckBoxes` are in a `GroupBox` then you have to use the `Controls` collection of the `GroupBox` rather than the form. Also, you can use a LINQ query to flatten your loop into a single statement:

```vb
Dim checkedBoxesCount = myGroupBox.Controls.
                                   OfType(Of CheckBox)().
                                   Count(Function(cb) cb.Checked)
```